# How to integrate functions of linearly interpolated data?

Tags: numerical-integration, interpolation, data

At first, consider integration of pure `InterpolatingFunction`.

Importing some data (works in v.9, for earlier versions one can use [this link](http://cramit.in/064d3xcuect6) to download zipped `M` file which can be imported by `data=Import["data.zip", "data.m"]`):

```
data = First@
   Import["http://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?JCAMP=C67561&Index=17&Type=IR"];
```

Transforming the data according to an integrand:

```
integrand[ww_, k_] := k/ww
dataF = {#1, integrand[#1, #2]} & @@@ data;
```

Now interpolation and integration:

```
In[13]:= int = Interpolation[dataF, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
ni = NIntegrate[int[ww], {ww, dataF[[1, 1]], dataF[[-1, 1]]}]
```

> ```
> During evaluation of In[13]:= NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to
> converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive bisections in ww
> near {ww} = {1053.057940138439}. NIntegrate obtained 0.000035786622823277624
> and 1.6106181332828143*^-6 for the integral and error estimates. >>
>
> Out[14]= 0.0000357866
> ```

I am confused by unexpectedly high absolute error (see next) and strange error `Message` generated by `NIntegrate` when integrating function of linearly interpolated data.
Note that `NIntegrate` fails to converge on linear (!) piece of the polyline:

```
In[15]:= Nearest[dataF[[All, 1]], 1053.057940138439`, 2]
```

> ```
> Out[15]= {1053.0705299372542, 1053.010264968627}
> ```

`Integrate` is able to integrate pure `InterpolatingFunction`s:

```
i = Integrate[int[ww], {ww, dataF[[1, 1]], dataF[[-1, 1]]}]
```

> ```
> 0.00003537589327711996
> ```

We can check it by direct integration:

```
exactSum = 
 MovingAverage[dataF[[All, 2]], 2].Differences[dataF[[All, 1]]]
```

> ```
> 0.00003537589420603186
> ```

The differences:

```
{ni, i} - exactSum
```

> ```
> {4.10729*10^-7, -9.28912*10^-13}
> ```

One can see the large error for `NIntegate` output. Increasing `PrecisionGoal` and `MaxRecursion` does not give much:

```
ni = NIntegrate[int[ww], {ww, dataF[[1, 1]], dataF[[-1, 1]]}, 
   MaxRecursion -> 25, PrecisionGoal -> 16] // Quiet
exactSum - ni
```

> ```
> 0.000035342690008474926
>
> 3.32042*10^-8
> ```

At this point my questions are:

1. Why `NIntegrate` fails to converge when interpolating the polyline? Why it has biggest trouble not even on a node but on a linear piece of the polyline?
2. Is it possible to achieve for `NIntegrate` at least the same precision as it is for `Integrate`? Or, better, as it is for direct summation?

Now I wish to integrate a function of linearly interpolated data:

```
int2 = Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
ni2 = NIntegrate[int2[ww]/ww, {ww, data[[1, 1]], data[[-1, 1]]}, 
   MaxRecursion -> 22, PrecisionGoal -> 19] // Quiet
```

> ```
> 0.000035342690032342044
> ```

`Integrate` cannot work with functions of interpolated data at all. Direct summation gives:

```
area[{w1_, k1_}, {w2_, k2_}] = 
  Integrate[(a + b ww)/ww, {ww, w1, w2}, PrincipalValue -> True] /. 
    First@Solve[a + b w1 == k1 && a + b w2 == k2, {a, b}] // Simplify;
exactSum = Total[area @@@ Partition[data, 2, 1]]

exactSum - ni2
```

> ```
> 0.000035375894186915904
>
> 3.32042*10^-8
> ```

Again, I get very large error. It is not always possible to get closed-form formula for direct summation. So the final question is: **what is the best way to integrate smooth functions of linearly interpolated data with high precision?**

Comment: Your code doesn't work with the data you have posted. In fact `First@Import....` is a header and the table is not formatted properly. It seems that the first 38 elements are headers and so is the last. Can you use `Import[...,"Table"]` and select only numbers `Select[#, NumberQ]/@` then see if you can reproduce it?

Comment: `Plot[Derivative[-1][int][ww], {ww, dataF[[1, 1]], dataF[[-1, 1]]}, Evaluated -> True]` looks okay?

Comment: @ Oleksandr Yes, [it is OK](http://i.imgur.com/946baGT.png).

Comment: @gpap I just checked again, it works (version 9.0.0)! `ListLogPlot[data, PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True]` gives me [this](http://i.imgur.com/5g93hmI.png).

Comment: @gpap In versions <9 my `Import` code will not work since [support of the `jdx` (`JCAMP-DX`) format is added in version 9](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/JCAMP-DX.html). I'll try to find a workaround.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov yup, sorry - should have specified my version (8).

Comment: @gpap You can use [this link](http://filecloud.io/y8f9u7ho) to download zipped `M` file which can be imported in v.8 by `data=Import["data.zip", "data.m"]`.

Comment: Thanks, works now but @AlbertRetey seems to have solved it anyway.

Comment: @gpap: it worked for me as I was using version 9. I think that the options I suggest for `NIntegrate` are also relatively new and only available since version 8.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Update:

After identifying and fixing a problem with `data`, we show that the setting the `"MaxSubregions"` option of `"InterpolationPointsSubdivision"` to the number intervals created by the interpolation points produces a highly accurate answer in a reasonably short amount of time.

#### Verify the data!

Ahhh, this is maddening: there's problem with the data.  One of the points (the 7th) is out of order and causes `exactSum` to be off by `-9.28912*10^-13`, which coincides the "error" of my first answer.  If we fix this by sorting the data and recomputing the "exact" sum, the error is greatly diminished.  The first answer (see below) turns out to be highly accurate and fast (for `NIntegrate`).

Here is the offending datum:

```
data[[4 ;; 8]]

(*  {{575.171, -2.41302*10^-7}, {575.231, -6.9385*10^-8},
     {575.291, 8.54164*10^-7}, {575.29, 2.06936*10^-6}, (* <-- here *)
     {575.35, 3.80004*10^-6}} *)
```

Here is the corrected exact sum, `exactSumSorted`, and the comparison with `exactSum`:

```
integrand[ww_, k_] := k/ww
dataF = {#1, integrand[#1, #2]} & @@@ data;
dataFSorted = {#1, integrand[#1, #2]} & @@@ Sort@data;
exactSum = MovingAverage[dataF[[All, 2]], 2].Differences[dataF[[All, 1]]]
exactSumSorted = MovingAverage[dataFSorted[[All, 2]], 2] .
                   Differences[dataFSorted[[All, 1]]]
(*              !
   0.00003537589420603182` 
   0.000035375893277120126`
                ^            *)

exactSumSorted - exactSum
(*
   -9.28912*10^-13
*)
```

Comparison of first answer with the sums:

```
ni - exactSum
ni - exactSumSorted
(*
   -9.28912*10^-13
   -1.76183*10^-19
*)
```

Now the relative error,

```
(ni - exactSumSorted)/exactSumSorted
(* 
   -4.98031*10^-15
*)
```

is much more in line with what is expected.

#### The second integral

I omitted to deal with the second integral in my first answer, but it was what got me curious about what was going on.  The graph of `int2[ww] / ww` should be piecewise concave up and the trapezoid rule should overestimate the integral, but the reverse was happening.

We can get the exact sum of the integrals over the subregions of the interpolating function in a way similar to how Alexey Popkov got the exact sum for the integral of the linear interpolation.  First observe the following.  If value of a function `y = f[x]` is linearly interpolated between the values `y1`, `y2`, as `x` ranges from `x1` to `x2`, then we can compute the integral of `f[x]/x` as follows:

```
Integrate[((1 - t) y1 + t y2)/((1 - t) x1 + t x2) (x2 - x1), {t, 0, 1},
  Assumptions -> {x2 > x1 > 0}]
(*
   -y1 + y2 + ((-x2 y1 + x1 y2) Log[x2/x1])/(x1 - x2)
*)
```

[**Update 2:** *Further explanation.*  First, it was easier for me to think abstractly in terms of `x` and `y`; the correspondence is `x = ww` and `y = int2[ww]`.  Switching to TeX, a linear interpolation between any two values $A$, $B$ is given by
$$(1-t)\,A + t\, B, \quad 0 \le t \le 1\,.$$
(Clearly it is linear in $t$ and ranges from $A$ to $B$ as $t$ ranges from $0$ to $1$.  Applying this to a subregion $x_1 \le x \le x_2$ where $y$ is interpolated linearly between the values $y_1 = {\tt int2}(x_1)$ and $y_2 = {\tt int2}(x_2)$, we can paramterize the interpolation by
$$ y = (1-t)\,y_1 + t\,y_2,\quad
   x = (1-t)\,x_1 + t\,x_2 = x_1 + t\,(x_2 - x_1), \quad
   0 \le t \le 1.$$
Substituting into the integral, this becomes
$$\int_{ww_1}^{ww_2} {{\tt int2}(ww) \over ww}\;d(ww) =
  \int_{x_1}^{x_2} {y \over x}\;dx =
  \int_{0}^{1} {(1-t)\,y_1 + t\,y_2 \over (1-t)\,x_1 + t\,x_2}\;(x_2-x_1)\,dt\,,$$
where the factor $x_2-x_1 = dx/dt$.  This corresponds to the *Mathematica* integral above.  To get the integral over the whole data set, we just total up the values of this integral over all of the subregions, which we do below to get `exactSum2`.]

Thus the exact value (ignoring machine precision error) can be calculated with

```
With[{data = Sort@data},
 exactSum2 = Total[
    -First @ Differences[               (* -x2 y1 + x1 y2 *)
        Reverse @ Transpose @ Most[data] Transpose @ Rest[data]] *
      Log @ Ratios[data[[All, 1]]] /    (* Log[x2/x1] *)
      Differences[data[[All, 1]]]       (* x1 - x2 -- note minus in front *)
    ] + data[[-1, 2]] - data[[1, 2]]    (* telescoping y2 - y1 *)
 ]
(*
   0.00003537589326824584`
*)
```

The integral may be computed, using the same `"InterpolationPointsSubdivision"` options as in the first answer, with

```
int2 = Interpolation[Sort@data, InterpolationOrder -> 1];

(ni2 = NIntegrate[int2[ww]/ww, 
   Evaluate[{ww}~Join~First@int2["Domain"]], 
   Method -> {"InterpolationPointsSubdivision", 
     "MaxSubregions" -> 1 + Length[First@int2["Coordinates"]]}
   ]) // AbsoluteTiming
(*
   {29.845430, 0.00003537589326907005`}
                               ^         *)
```

Compared to Alexey Popkov's similar version, we see the above is a little faster and agrees with Alexey's up to the last digit.

```
(ni2AP = NIntegrate[int2[ww]/ww, 
   Evaluate[{ww}~Join~First@int2["Domain"]], 
   Method -> {"InterpolationPointsSubdivision", 
     "MaxSubregions" -> 10^9, 
     Method -> {"LocalAdaptive", MaxPoints -> Infinity, Method -> {"TrapezoidalRule"}}}
   ]) // AbsoluteTiming
(*
   {31.126306, 0.000035375893269070053`}
                               ^     ^    *)
```

The error is about the best that could be expected:

```
{ni2, ni2AP} - exactSum2
(*
   {8.24204*10^-16, 8.2421*10^-16}
*)
```

For one thing, as a very rough estimate, we can estimate that about four digits or more of precision might be lost just from differences of the first coordinate:

```
Max @ Abs[(Rest[#] - Most[#])/Most[#]] &@ Sort@data[[All, 1]]
(*
   0.000119089
*)
```

[**Update 2:** I should have stressed that this is a crude estimate I used to give me an idea of what a reasonable error between `NIntegrate` and `exactSum` might be.  The errors are probably randomly distributed and some probably cancel others.  Also the greatest loss of precision in a single difference would be indicated by `Min` instead of `Max` (about 6 digits).  So the actual error might vary widely from this estimate.  The calculation above is based on this sort of example:  Consider the two numbers below and their absolute difference:

```
0.00001234123
0.00001234567
-------------
0.00000000444 (abs. val. of difference)
```

We went from 7 digits to 3 digits of precision.  The relative difference is

```
(0.00001234567 - 0.00001234123)/0.00001234567
(*
   0.00035964
*)
```

The number of digits lost is indicated by the logarithm:

```
Log10[0.00035964]
(*
   -3.44413
*)
```

*End of update 2.*]

### First answer

To get a complete `"InterpolationPointsSubdivision"`, a sufficient number of subregions needs to be allowed with the `"MaxSubregions"` option.  This allows `NIntegrate` to handle the 50K+ subintervals in the interpolating function `int`.

```
data = First @
  Import["http://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?JCAMP=C67561&Index=17&Type=IR"];
integrand[ww_, k_] := k/ww
dataF = {#1, integrand[#1, #2]} & @@@ data;
int = Interpolation[dataF, InterpolationOrder -> 1];

(ni =
   NIntegrate[
     int[ww],
     Evaluate[{ww} ~Join~ First@int["Domain"]], 
     Method -> {"InterpolationPointsSubdivision", 
                "MaxSubregions" -> 1 + Length[First@int["Coordinates"]]}]
 ) // AbsoluteTiming

(* {0.129937, 0.0000353759} *)
```

I'm not sure why one more subregion is needed than coordinates/data points.  I suppose it is because N coordinates divide the real numbers into N+1 regions, ignoring the interval of integration.

### Postscript: More of the story

Every now and then I tried `NIntegrate` with some other option, even increasing `WorkingPrecision`, to see if the integral would get closer to the exact value.  It was the stubborn resistance of `NIntegrate` to get the relative error down to close to `10^-15`, or even `10^-12`, that made me suspect that `NIntegrate` was right and `exactSum` was wrong.

Here is something I found along the way that pleased me.  Nothing earth shattering, but when a numerical method returns an error that is essentially zero, it's fun.

I used arbitrary precision numbers with 30 digits of precision.  They can be quite a bit slower.  Here is the exact value.

```
(With[{data = SetPrecision[Sort@data, 30]},
  exactSum2p = Total[
     -First @ Differences[               (* -x2 y1 + x1 y2 *)
         Reverse @ Transpose @ Most[data] Transpose @ Rest[data]] *
       Log @ Ratios[data[[All, 1]]] /    (* Log[x2/x1] *)
       Differences[data[[All, 1]]]       (* x1 - x2 -- note minus in front *)
     ] + data[[-1, 2]] - data[[1, 2]]    (* telescoping y2 - y1 *)
   ]) // AbsoluteTiming
(*
   {0.722450, 0.00003537589326907000957268}
*)
```

The machine precision calculation took `0.008799` sec.  `NIntegrate` will be much slower, too.

```
int2p = Interpolation[SetPrecision[Sort@data, 30], InterpolationOrder -> 1];
(ni2p = NIntegrate[int2p[ww]/ww, 
    Evaluate[{ww} ~Join~ First@int2p["Domain"]],
    Method -> {"InterpolationPointsSubdivision", 
      "MaxSubregions" -> 1 + Length[First@int2p["Coordinates"]]},
    WorkingPrecision -> 30
    ]) // AbsoluteTiming
(*
   {160.618752, 0.0000353758932690700095726756654469}
*)
```

Here is a comparison of the results:

```
Print[ni2p // InputForm]
Print[exactSum2p // InputForm]
(*
   0.000035375893269070009572675665446947030350735701361289965`21.891735884879235
   0.0000353758932690700095726756654469470303507494495353721558`30.
                              ^ 22nd            ^ 39th (1st difference)  *)

ni2p - exactSum2p // InputForm
(*
  0``26.343028466547207  (* StandardForm: 0.*10^-27 *)
*)
```

The last output means the first 26+ digits after the decimal place are zero.  This corresponds to `exactSum2p` having almost 22 digits of precision and its first nonzero digit being the 5th after the decimal point.

Comment: (+1). Your solution gives amazing speedup in integration of pure `InterpolatingFunction` and significant speedup in integration of the `int2[ww]/ww`. But `"MaxSubregions"` suboption is completely undocumented: [searching](http://search.wolfram.com/?query=MaxSubregions&collection=tryonall) on all Wolfram websites gives no results. Where did you find it?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov I put in a wrong option, e.g. `Method -> {"InterpolationPointsSubdivision", "Foo" -> 1}`, and *Mma* told the valid ones.

Comment: It is amazing! Such a crucially needed option can be found only esoterically! Even the form `Method -> {"InterpolationPointsSubdivision"}` is undocumented (I cannot find it in the Documentation).

Comment: It is interesting that `NIntegrate[int2[ww]/ww, {ww, data[[1, 1]], data[[-1, 1]]}, 
 Method -> {"InterpolationPointsSubdivision", 
   "MaxSubregions" -> 10^9}]` gives even better performance but `"MaxSubregions" -> 10^10` is forbidden.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov After ``?*`*Subdivision*``, one finds ``NIntegrate`InterpolationPointsSubdivision``.  Thence ``Options[NIntegrate`InterpolationPointsSubdivision]`` yields the default settings, too.  This is good, too: ``?NIntegrate`StrategiesDump`*`` -- lots of options and properties.

Comment: It is great update! I need time to investigate it deeply.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov  Thanks.  I realized I omitted some of the explanation of the calculation of `exactSum2` -- now included.

Comment: I accept your great answer. Only two things remain a bit unclear: 1) the logics behind your parametrization `((1 - t) y1 + t y2)/((1 - t) x1 + t x2) (x2 - x1)` (section "The second integral"), 2) why do you think that `Max @ Abs[(Rest[#] - Most[#])/Most[#]] &@ Sort@data[[All, 1]]` gives an estimate of precision loss (the last paragraph in the same section)?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Thanks!  I added the derivation of the interpolation and integral. I added some explanation of the estimate of precision loss, too.  I should have stressed that was far from an exact calculation.

Answer (score 15):

`NIntegrate` has many advanced options that let you control which algorithms and strategies it will use. I'm quite sure that you can find a set of options that will make `NIntegrate` work well enough for the desired task, but of course these numerical algorithms will never be quite as fast and precise as an exact solution, which your sums and `Integrate`s results basically are.

A relatively obvious but poorly documented and probably still not optimal choice for integrands containing interpolating functions is the preprocessor method `"InterpolationPointsSubdivision"`. With it and the strategy `"LocalAdaptive"`, I already get a substantial improvement by just "blindly" playing with the available options, e.g. for your first example:

```
ni = 
 NIntegrate[int[ww], {ww, dataF[[1, 1]], dataF[[-1, 1]]}, 
  Method -> {"InterpolationPointsSubdivision", 
    Method -> {"LocalAdaptive", "Partitioning" -> 10}},
  PrecisionGoal -> 9
  ]
exactSum - ni

(*
==> 0.0000353759
*)

(*
==> 6.65151*10^-13
*)
```

and also for your second example:

```
ni3 = 
 NIntegrate[int2[ww]/ww, {ww, data[[1, 1]], data[[-1, 1]]}, 
  Method -> {"InterpolationPointsSubdivision", 
    Method -> {"LocalAdaptive", "Partitioning" -> 15}},
  PrecisionGoal -> 9]
ni3 - exactSum

(*
==> 0.0000353759
*)

(*
==> 1.99279*10^-12
*)
```

With the given options `NIntegrate` doesn't throw any errors/warnings but is relatively slow. I'm not considering myself an expert in numeric integration and it looks like your own background would probably let you choose something even better. I would suggest to look at the [tutorial advanced numeric integration](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NIntegrateOverview.html) and see how far you get. I see there some options which I don't fully understand but could well imagine to be of help for this case. You also might try the WRI support, if such a question is forwarded to the developers you might get a very good answer (if not, answers are not always very impressive). If my experience with `NDSolve` can be extrapolated to `NIntegrate` I would expect there is a set of options which should provide a good result in decent time, but that kind of problem (56000 data points with several sharp peaks and quite some noice or oscillations) is clearly something that needs an approach which gives `NIntegrate` some hints about what the characteristics of that function are...

**Edit**: as Alexey has found the improvement in precision is actually independent of the method setting `"InterpolationPointsSubdivision"`, it's rather the combination of `"LocalAdaptive"`, `"Partitioning"` and `PrecisionGoal` that makes a difference. Thus for this example these somewhat simpler settings seem to give results with equal quality:

```
 NIntegrate[int[ww], {ww, dataF[[1, 1]], dataF[[-1, 1]]}, 
  Method -> {"LocalAdaptive", "Partitioning" -> 10},
  PrecisionGoal -> 9
 ]
```

I don't understand the precise effect of each of these settings in every detail and just stopped playing when I found a combination that seemed to work well. For other problems it might make sense to play with any of these or -- even better -- to study the problem and documentation in more depth...

Comment: (+1) It is strange but it seems that specifying the `"InterpolationPointsSubdivision"` preprocessor changes nothing in both cases: compare `NIntegrate[int[ww], {ww, dataF[[1, 1]], dataF[[-1, 1]]}, Method -> {"LocalAdaptive", "Partitioning" -> 10}, PrecisionGoal -> 9]` with `NIntegrate[int[ww], {ww, dataF[[1, 1]], dataF[[-1, 1]]}, Method -> {"InterpolationPointsSubdivision", Method -> {"LocalAdaptive", "Partitioning" -> 10}}, PrecisionGoal -> 9]`. The outputs are identical.

Comment: I also tried to switch `"InterpolationPointsSubdivision"` off and got the same result: `NIntegrate[int[ww], {ww, dataF[[1, 1]], dataF[[-1, 1]]}, Method -> {"SymbolicPreprocessing", "InterpolationPointsSubdivision" -> False, Method -> {"LocalAdaptive", "Partitioning" -> 10}}, PrecisionGoal -> 9]`. `AbsoluteTiming`s are also identical. It is just `"LocalAdaptive"` strategy makes good job.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov: I tried to make sure that I just played around with those options and it turns out that you are right: With just `"InterpolationPointsSubdivision"` the difference to the "exact sum" is not better than `Automatic`, it is the combination of `"LocalAdaptive"`, `"Partitioning"` and `PrecisionGoal` that seems to make a difference. Certainly there is room for more investigation and optimization...

Answer (score 9):

---

**UPDATE 2 start**

As [Michael has shown](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/39403/280), semi-documented preprocessor `"InterpolationPointsSubdivision"` with undocumented `"MaxSubregions" -> 10^9` suboption gives significant speedup in both cases. So the complete `Method` option should be:

```
Method -> {"InterpolationPointsSubdivision", "MaxSubregions" -> 10^9, 
  Method -> {"LocalAdaptive", MaxPoints -> Infinity, 
    Method -> {"TrapezoidalRule"}}}
```

The rest of the answer does not include this update.

It is interesting that switching off `"SymbolicProcessing"` suboption gives a little better performance in this case:

```
Method -> {"InterpolationPointsSubdivision", "MaxSubregions" -> 10^9, 
  "SymbolicProcessing" -> False}
```

**UPDATE 2 end**

---

**UPDATE start**

In both cases (integration of `int[ww]` and `int2[ww]/ww`, i.e. direct integration of the `InterpolatingFunction` and integration of the function of the `InterpolatingFunction`) selection of the `"TrapezoidalRule"` integration rule significantly improves the performance without noticeable loss of precision. So complete `Method` option should look like this in both cases:

```
Method -> {"LocalAdaptive", Method -> {"TrapezoidalRule"}}
```

The rest of the answer does not include this update.

**UPDATE end**

---

### Solution using `NIntegrate` of *Mathematica* 6+ (9.0.1)

One can achieve for integrating `InterpolatingFunction` by `NIntegrate` the same precision as with `Integrate` by specifying explicit set of `Exclusions` and `MaxRecursion->0` (although the timings are disappointing):

```
integrand[ww_, k_] := k/ww
dataF = {#1, integrand[#1, #2]} & @@@ data;
int = Interpolation[dataF, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
ni1 = NIntegrate[int[ww], {ww, dataF[[1, 1]], dataF[[-1, 1]]}, 
    MaxRecursion -> 0, PrecisionGoal -> 16, 
    Exclusions -> dataF[[2 ;; -2, 1]]]; // AbsoluteTiming
ni2 = NIntegrate[int[ww], Evaluate@Prepend[dataF[[All, 1]], ww], 
    MaxRecursion -> 0, PrecisionGoal -> 16]; // AbsoluteTiming
i1 = Integrate[int[ww], {ww, dataF[[1, 1]], dataF[[-1, 1]]}]; // AbsoluteTiming
exactSum = 
   MovingAverage[dataF[[All, 2]], 2].Differences[
     dataF[[All, 1]]]; // AbsoluteTiming
{ni1, ni2} - i1
{ni1, ni2, i1} - exactSum
{ni1, ni2, i1, exactSum} // InputForm
```

> ```
> During evaluation of In[1]:= NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 0 recursive bisections in ww near {ww} = {1034.51}. NIntegrate obtained 0.00003537589327712014` and 5.3740022820734247`*^-20 for the integral and error estimates. >>
>
> Out[5]= {171.515625, Null}
>
> During evaluation of In[1]:= NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 0 recursive bisections in ww near {ww} = {575.35}. NIntegrate obtained 0.000035375893282044965` and 3.621199488108469`*^-12 for the integral and error estimates. >>
>
> Out[6]= {150.656250, Null}
>
> Out[7]= {0.250000, Null}
>
> Out[8]= {0.031250, Null}
>
> Out[9]= {1.76183*10^-19, 4.925*10^-15}
>
> Out[10]= {-9.28912*10^-13, -9.23987*10^-13, -9.28912*10^-13}
>
> Out[11]//InputForm=
> {0.00003537589327712014, 0.000035375893282044965, 0.00003537589327711996, 
>  0.00003537589420603182}
> ```

Using the `"LocalAdaptive"` strategy and non-zero `MaxRecursion` in the same manner one can increase precision of integration of smooth function of `InterpolatingFunction`:

```
int2 = Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
ni3 = NIntegrate[int2[ww]/ww, {ww, data[[1, 1]], data[[-1, 1]]}, 
    MaxRecursion -> 12, PrecisionGoal -> 16, Exclusions -> data[[2 ;; -2, 1]],
     Method -> "LocalAdaptive"]; // AbsoluteTiming
ni4 = NIntegrate[int2[ww]/ww, Evaluate@Prepend[dataF[[All, 1]], ww], 
    MaxRecursion -> 12, PrecisionGoal -> 16, 
    Method -> "LocalAdaptive"]; // AbsoluteTiming
area[{w1_, k1_}, {w2_, k2_}] = 
  Integrate[(a + b ww)/ww, {ww, w1, w2}, PrincipalValue -> True] /. 
    First@Solve[a + b w1 == k1 && a + b w2 == k2, {a, b}] // Simplify;
exactSum2 = Total[area @@@ Partition[data, 2, 1]]; // AbsoluteTiming
{ni1, ni2} - exactSum
{ni1, ni2, exactSum} // InputForm
```

> ```
> Out[13]= {197.421875, Null}
>
> Out[14]= {169.859375, Null}
>
> Out[16]= {1.015625, Null}
>
> Out[17]= {-9.28912*10^-13, -9.23987*10^-13}
>
> Out[18]//InputForm=
> {0.00003537589327712014, 0.000035375893282044965, 0.00003537589420603182}
> ```

---

### `NIntegrate` of *Mathematica* 5.2

I should also point out that in *Mathematica* 5.2 one can get the same precision using only `MaxRecursion` and `PrecisionGoal` options and much faster, addition of exclusions makes it even faster:

```
In[4]:= << Statistics`DataSmoothing`

data = << data.m;
integrand[ww_, k_] := k/ww
dataF = {#1, integrand[#1, #2]} & @@@ data;
int = Interpolation[dataF, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
ni1 = NIntegrate[int[ww], {ww, dataF[[1, 1]], dataF[[-1, 1]]}, 
    MaxRecursion -> 25, PrecisionGoal -> 16]; // AbsoluteTiming
ni2 = NIntegrate[int[ww], Evaluate@Prepend[dataF[[All, 1]], ww], 
    MaxRecursion -> 0, PrecisionGoal -> 16, 
    SingularityDepth -> 0]; // AbsoluteTiming
i = Integrate[int[ww], {ww, dataF[[1, 1]], dataF[[-1, 1]]}]; // AbsoluteTiming
exactSum = 
   MovingAverage[dataF[[All, 2]], 
     2].(Rest@dataF[[All, 1]] - Most@dataF[[All, 1]]); // AbsoluteTiming
{ni1, ni2} - i
{ni1, ni2, i} - exactSum
{ni1, ni2, i, exactSum} // InputForm
```

> ```
> From In[4]:= NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration being 0, oscillatory integrand, or insufficient WorkingPrecision. If your integrand is oscillatory try using the option Method->Oscillatory in NIntegrate. More\[Ellipsis]
>
> From In[4]:= NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 26 recursive bisections in ww near ww = 1033.9707945203033`. More\[Ellipsis]
>
> Out[9]= {79.5937500 Second, Null}
>
> From In[4]:= NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 2 recursive bisections in ww near ww = 575.2930004161132`. More\[Ellipsis]
>
> Out[10]= {37.2656250 Second, Null}
>
> Out[11]= {0.2656250 Second, Null}
>
> Out[12]= {0.0468750 Second, Null}
>
> Out[13]= {-5.34626*10^-14, 6.48336*10^-13}
>
> Out[14]= {-9.82374*10^-13, -2.80576*10^-13, -9.28912*10^-13}
>
> Out[15]//InputForm=
> {0.000035375893223657405, 0.00003537589392545566, 0.00003537589327711996, 
>  0.000035375894206031784}
> ```

```
In[16]:= int2 = Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
ni3 = NIntegrate[int2[ww]/ww, {ww, data[[1, 1]], data[[-1, 1]]}, 
    MaxRecursion -> 25, PrecisionGoal -> 16]; // AbsoluteTiming
ni4 = NIntegrate[int2[ww]/ww, Evaluate@Prepend[data[[All, 1]], ww], 
    MaxRecursion -> 12, PrecisionGoal -> 16]; // AbsoluteTiming
area[{w1_, k1_}, {w2_, k2_}] = 
  Integrate[(a + b ww)/ww, {ww, w1, w2}, PrincipalValue -> True] /. 
    First@Solve[a + b w1 == k1 && a + b w2 == k2, {a, b}] // Simplify;
exactSum2 = Total[area @@@ Partition[data, 2, 1]]; // AbsoluteTiming

{ni3, ni4} - exactSum2
{ni3, ni4, exactSum2} // InputForm
```

> ```
> From In[16]:= NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration being 0, oscillatory integrand, or insufficient WorkingPrecision. If your integrand is oscillatory try using the option Method->Oscillatory in NIntegrate. More\[Ellipsis]
>
> From In[16]:= NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 26 recursive bisections in ww near ww = 1033.9707945203033`. More\[Ellipsis]
>
> Out[17]= {84.7031250 Second, Null}
>
> From In[16]:= NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration being 0, oscillatory integrand, or insufficient WorkingPrecision. If your integrand is oscillatory try using the option Method->Oscillatory in NIntegrate. More\[Ellipsis]
>
> From In[16]:= NIntegrate::tmap: NIntegrate is unable to achieve the tolerances specified by the PrecisionGoal and AccuracyGoal options because the working precision is insufficient.  Try increasing the setting of the WorkingPrecision option.
>
> Out[18]= {39.8593750 Second, Null}
>
> Out[20]= {1.8281250 Second, Null}
>
> Out[21]= {-9.83531*10^-13, -9.3084*10^-13}
>
> Out[22]//InputForm=
> {0.00003537589321637961, 0.000035375893269070094, 0.00003537589419991056}
> ```

---

All the above timings I have got on the same machine.

Comment: Related: "[How to speed up Integration of interpolation function?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/115860/280)"

Answer (score 8):

You can try to force `NIntegrate` into doing a similar approach than you did by calculating the sum directly. This reduces your error quite a bit, although I don't understand the reasons behind this exercise:

```
ni = NIntegrate[int[ww], {ww, dataF[[1, 1]], dataF[[-1, 1]]}, 
  Method -> {"TrapezoidalRule", 
    "Points" -> Length[dataF]}, MaxRecursion -> 0]
(* difference is -1.97858*10^-11 *)
```

Comment: My point is not integrating the `InterpolatingFunction` (it can be done with `Integrate`) but integrating a smooth function of linearly interpolated data. I even do not insist on using `NIntegate` for this. I still have no good solution for the case when the closed form of the integral cannot be derived.

Comment: @halirutan: do you know where the `"Points"` option for `"TrapezoidalRule"` is documented and what exactly it does?

Comment: @AlbertRetey [Here it is documented](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationRules.html#245149443).

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov: thanks, that's useful. Actually it is where one could expect to find it, I obviously just didn't try hard enough...

Comment: @AlbertRetey Sorry for not answering to your comment. Somehow I must have missed it. I see that it is already from February.. better late than never.

Comment: @halirutan: no problem, I didn't remember it was an open question until Alexey answered :-).