# Integrate with FunctionInterpolation differs from NIntegrate

Tags: numerical-integration, interpolation

In working with interpolating functions and integration, I noticed a lot of differences between `NIntegrate` and `Integrate` in the case of a function applied to an interpolating function.
In order to provide a simple example, look at this output:

```
ifun = Interpolation[ {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 3}, {5, 0}}]
NIntegrate[x*ifun[x], {x, 0, 5}]
```

> ```
> 32.5694
> ```

```
xifun = FunctionInterpolation[x*ifun[x], {x, 0, 5}]
```

> FunctionInterpolation::precbd: Requested precision [Infinity] is not a machine-sized real number between \$MinPrecision and \$MaxPrecision. >>

```
out = Integrate[xifun[x], {x, 0, 5}];
N[out]
```

> ```
> 32.591
> ```

The difference is at the second decimal place, or of the order of 0.06%.
For more complicated functions (lots of data values and Bessel functions, I get errors of more than 100%).

I would like to know the reason of the error. In my real-life example I only get correct answers using the `NIntegrate` method.

I know there is this other question: [How to integrate functions of linearly interpolated data?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18863/how-to-integrate-functions-of-linearly-interpolated-data)

But they don't use `FunctionInterpolation` and I think that there should be a simple explanation for this difference. My data is also not linearly-interpolated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a whirl:

```
ifun = Interpolation[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 3}, {5, 0}}];
out1 = NIntegrate[x*ifun[x], {x, 0, 5}];

xifun = FunctionInterpolation[x*ifun[x], {x, 0, 5, .01}];
out2 = Integrate[xifun[x], {x, 0, 5}];

Row[{out1, N[out2]}, "    "]

(*  32.5694    32.5694  *)
```

Comment: This third argument appears with color red in my Mathematica 9 version. That means that it shouldn't go there. I also didn't find it in the  documentation. I tried it anyway and it indeed works for the more complicated case! What is it, the precision?

Comment: @Santi. The syntax highlighter isn't infalible. It sometimes rejects a form that works -- maybe because the the function involved has been recently changed and the syntax editor didn't get updated with the change. I've encountered this with functions other than `FunctionInterpolation`. Go with what works.

Comment: Ok thanks, it definitely worked! But what is exactly that third argument?

Comment: @Santi Evaluation of `xifun["Grid"] // Differences` reveals that the third argument is just the sampling step.

Comment: @Santi: Sorry for delay responding, needed sleep! As Alexy said, it is sample step - I discovered this some time ago, figured it was common knowledge, sorry for not explicitly defining it and causing confusion.

Comment: `FunctionInterpolation::precbd` error will be surpressed if one changes the range to be machine precision number i.e. `{x,0,5}` to be `{x,0.,5}` (@Santi). Very odd.