# Integration of any interpolation generates invalid comparison errors

Tags: numerical-integration, interpolation

Integrating a simple interpolated function as follows generates invalid comparison errors.

```
In[545]:= f= Interpolation[{{0., 0.}, {1., 1.}}, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
NIntegrate[f[0.5 + 0.5 x^2], {x, 0.0, 1.0}]

During evaluation of In[545]:= Less::nord: Invalid comparison with 0. -1. I attempted. >>
During evaluation of In[545]:= Less::nord: Invalid comparison with 0. -1. I attempted. >>
During evaluation of In[545]:= Less::nord: Invalid comparison with 0. -1. I attempted. >>
During evaluation of In[545]:= General::stop: Further output of Less::nord will be suppressed during this calculation. >>
Out[546]= 0.666667
```

It seems that Mathematica tries to find a root of the argument in the function. Why? And how can it be prevented?

Comment: Change method to e.g. `Method -> "AdaptiveQuasiMonteCarlo"` to rid yourself of warnings.

Comment: Strongly related: "[How to integrate functions of linearly interpolated data?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18863/280)"

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov: Ah, thanks for linking, I knew there was a question covering this kind of thing in detail, didn't find it.

Comment: Small glitch. Will be addressed.