# How to speed up integration of interpolation function?

Tags: numerical-integration, interpolation

I have a list of data, and I interpolate it to a function. Then I need to do an integration with the interpolating function. But I found that the speed is unacceptably slow.

My data is here (a little long, but don't go away :) ):

```
data = {-0.00799443, -0.00581522, -0.00557107, -0.00543862, -0.00528042, \
-0.00508618, -0.00486091, -0.00461279, -0.00435009, -0.00408028, \
-0.0038098, -0.00354416, -0.00328805, -0.00304535, -0.00281906, \
-0.0026108, -0.00242045, -0.00224588, -0.00208332, -0.00192845, \
-0.00177801, -0.00163133, -0.00149092, -0.00136145, -0.0012474, \
-0.00115024, -0.00106716, -0.000992246, -0.000919878, -0.000848073, \
-0.000779184, -0.000717175, -0.000663667, -0.000616407, -0.00057173, \
-0.000528424, -0.000488614, -0.000454547, -0.000425288, -0.000397686, \
-0.000370268, -0.00034446, -0.000321488, -0.00030009, -0.000278782, \
-0.000258483, -0.000240725, -0.000224931, -0.000209972, -0.000196452, \
-0.000184918, -0.000174195, -0.000163592, -0.000153752, -0.000144418, \
-0.000134884, -0.000125771, -0.000117444, -0.000109436, -0.000102175, \
-0.0000959463, -0.0000902133, -0.000085125, -0.0000806452, \
-0.0000762082, -0.0000719591, -0.0000677566, -0.000063368, \
-0.0000591507, -0.0000549953, -0.0000510613, -0.0000475951, \
-0.0000444333, -0.0000417897, -0.0000394736, -0.0000373836, \
-0.0000354749, -0.0000334705, -0.0000314543, -0.0000292503, \
-0.0000269879, -0.0000247026, -0.0000224853, -0.0000204942, \
-0.0000187118, -0.0000172668, -0.0000160166, -0.0000149913, \
-0.0000139883, -0.0000129844, -0.000011827, -0.0000105289, \
-9.06132*10^-6, -7.50783*10^-6, -5.94092*10^-6, -4.46213*10^-6, \
-3.15097*10^-6, -2.0399*10^-6, -1.13236*10^-6, -3.57489*10^-7, 
 3.57489*10^-7, 1.13236*10^-6, 2.0399*10^-6, 3.15097*10^-6, 
 4.46213*10^-6, 5.94092*10^-6, 7.50783*10^-6, 
 9.06132*10^-6, 0.0000105289, 0.000011827, 0.0000129844, \
0.0000139883, 0.0000149913, 0.0000160166, 0.0000172668, 0.0000187118, \
0.0000204942, 0.0000224853, 0.0000247026, 0.0000269879, 0.0000292503, \
0.0000314543, 0.0000334705, 0.0000354749, 0.0000373836, 0.0000394736, \
0.0000417897, 0.0000444333, 0.0000475951, 0.0000510613, 0.0000549953, \
0.0000591507, 0.000063368, 0.0000677566, 0.0000719591, 0.0000762082, \
0.0000806452, 0.000085125, 0.0000902133, 0.0000959463, 0.000102175, \
0.000109436, 0.000117444, 0.000125771, 0.000134884, 0.000144418, \
0.000153752, 0.000163592, 0.000174195, 0.000184918, 0.000196452, \
0.000209972, 0.000224931, 0.000240725, 0.000258483, 0.000278782, \
0.00030009, 0.000321488, 0.00034446, 0.000370268, 0.000397686, \
0.000425288, 0.000454547, 0.000488614, 0.000528424, 0.00057173, \
0.000616407, 0.000663667, 0.000717175, 0.000779184, 0.000848073, \
0.000919878, 0.000992246, 0.00106716, 0.00115024, 0.0012474, \
0.00136145, 0.00149092, 0.00163133, 0.00177801, 0.00192845, \
0.00208332, 0.00224588, 0.00242045, 0.0026108, 0.00281906, \
0.00304535, 0.00328805, 0.00354416, 0.0038098, 0.00408028, \
0.00435009, 0.00461279, 0.00486091, 0.00508618, 0.00528042, \
0.00543862, 0.00557107, 0.00581522, 0.00799443}
```

Interpolate it:

```
f = Interpolation[data];
Plot[f[x], {x, 1, 200}, PlotRange -> All]
```

It looks like:

[image: interpolating function plot]

Now I define a function:

```
Clear[b];
b[x_, y_] := NIntegrate[
   Cross[{0, f[s], 0}, {x - s, 0, y}][[{1, 3}]]/((x - s)^2 + y^2),
   {s, 1, 200}
];
```

The integration is so slow!!

```
b[1., 2.] // AbsoluteTiming

(*{1.17772, {-0.00827965, -0.0104805}}*)
```

What I want to do is a vector plot:

```
VectorPlot[b[x, y], {x, -10, 210}, {y, -3, 3}]
```

But with this kind of slow integration, this is painful. Are there better ways to speed up the integration?

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18995/280

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The way to deal with this is to use the special setting `Method -> "InterpolationPointsSubdivision"` of `NIntegrate[]`, which will automagically split the integrand so that an integration rule (by default, `"GlobalAdaptive"`) is only applied within each piecewise polynomial interval of the `InterpolatingFunction[]` involved. This is akin to the functionality of the old package `` NumericalMath`NIntegrateInterpolatingFunct`​ ``.

As a demonstration:

```
With[{x = 5, y = 5}, 
     NIntegrate[Cross[{0, f[s], 0}, {x - s, 0, y}][[{1, 3}]]/((x - s)^2 + y^2),
                {s, 1, 200}]] // AbsoluteTiming
   {0.619479, {-0.00929476, -0.00291246}}

With[{x = 5, y = 5}, 
     NIntegrate[Cross[{0, f[s], 0}, {x - s, 0, y}][[{1, 3}]]/((x - s)^2 + y^2),
                {s, 1, 200}, Method -> "InterpolationPointsSubdivision"]] // AbsoluteTiming
   {0.0798281, {-0.00929476, -0.00291246}}
```

`` Options[NIntegrate`InterpolationPointsSubdivision] `` displays the suboptions that can be fed to this method.

Comment: Hi, J.M. This option works like magic. But I still don't understand how does it work. For example ``Options[NIntegrate`InterpolationPointsSubdivision]`` has option `MaxSubregion->1000`, what does it mean? To split the region into 1000 piece? And how does this makes interpolation function be integrated faster? Is the calculation times being reduced?

Comment: `MaxSubregion` gives the upper limit of how many subintervals should your integral be split into. As I already said, the splitting is done so that the integration methods are only applied into each of the piecewise polynomial regions; otherwise, it will waste time recursing at those breakpoints.

Comment: But why there is breakpoints? The data already been smoothed

Comment: It is only $C^1$ continuous, at the least.

Comment: I think I understand. So this option will automatically and exactly cut interpolation function at original data points, right?

Comment: Yes, unless the number of intervals exceeds the `MaxSubregion` setting.

Comment: @J.M. Awesome! The `InterpolationPointsSubdivision` option is not mentioned under the Details and Options section but is present in the `Method` -> `Symbolic Processing` section. Very happy to learned about this possibility. You get my vote.

Comment: @Jack, yes, it's tucked somewhere deep in the advanced documentation… one can be forgiven for not easily encountering it. :)

Answer (score 6):

An alternative to using [`NIntegrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate) is to convert the integral into an ODE, and then use [`NDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolveValue) or [`ParametricNDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricNDSolveValue). For example:

```
pf = ParametricNDSolveValue[
    {
    {u'[s], v'[s]} == Cross[{0,f[s],0}, {x-s,0,y}][[{1,3}]]/((x-s)^2+y^2),
    u[1]==0, v[1]==0
    },
    {u[200], v[200]},
    {s, 1, 200},
    {x, y}
];
```

Compare:

```
b[1, 2] //AbsoluteTiming
pf[1, 2] //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {1.11616, {-0.00827965, -0.0104805}}
>
> {0.004751, {-0.00827962, -0.0104802}}

Over 200 times faster with basically the same result. [`VectorPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VectorPlot) visualization:

```
VectorPlot[
    pf[x, y],
    {x, -10, 210},
    {y, -3, 3},
    VectorPoints -> {14, 14}
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you are willing to accept some error you can get a faster result by fitting the data to function.

Other than at each extreme the data looks like a shifted and scaled `Sinh` function.

Using your `data` (i.e., not re-copied)

```
sol = FindFit[data, 
  a Sinh[(x - x0)/b], {{a, 0.000015}, {b, 15}, {x0, 100}}, x]

(* {a -> 0.0000140493, b -> 14.3721, x0 -> 100.5} *)
```

Using the results define

```
f[x_] := 1.405*10^-5 Sinh[(x - 100.5)/14.37]
```

Here is the comparison

```
Show[
 ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> All],
 Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 200}, PlotStyle -> Black, PlotRange -> All]

 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I think I had to make sure that the inputs to `b` were numerical.

```
b[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[
  Cross[{0, f[s], 0}, {x - s, 0, y}][[{1, 3}]]/((x - s)^2 + y^2),
   {s, 1, 200}]
```

Using a fitted function enables you to pick up some speed (a factor ~ 80)

```
b[1., 2.] // AbsoluteTiming

(* {0.0143029, {-0.00872379, -0.0107461}} *)
```

and plot the vector plot (still slow, but not too painful).

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you find the error is too great you could try a `Piecewise` function and use the `Sinh` in the middle and fit a separate function at the end points. Looks like two lines on the right from 185 to 199 and 199 to 200 and on the left another two lines from 1 to 2 and 2 to 15 blended in with the `Sinh`.

I didn't try it so I don't know how it would affect performance.

Good luck!

Comment: Wow, you really captured the essential feature of my data. Your approach is really fast and the result is almost the same as accurate calculation. Great insight ! What is more, I tried `Piecewise` but found it generally harm the performance.

Comment: If it's really `Sinh` around 100.5, the integral is essentially odd about the middle of the domain.  The integral will be very very small as a result of large cancellations (and that may signal that your data is insufficient to get a good answer).

Answer (score 1):

If results with lower precision goals are satisfactory (which is an assumption in couple of the answers) then using `NIntegrate` with a combination of option settings for `Method` and `PrecisionGoal` can produce results much quicker.

In the table below the first two options settings are the same as in [J.M.'s answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/115870/34008). We can see that the last one is 100 times and 10 times quicker respectively.

```
opts = {{}, 
   Method -> 
    "InterpolationPointsSubdivision", {Method -> {Automatic, 
      "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}, PrecisionGoal -> 3}};

res =
  Table[
   With[{x = 5, y = 5, o1 = o},
    Prepend[
     AbsoluteTiming[
      NIntegrate[
       Cross[{0, f[s], 0}, {x - s, 0, y}][[{1, 3}]]/((x - s)^2 + 
          y^2), {s, 1, 200}, o1]], o1]
    ],
   {o, opts}];
TableForm[res, 
 TableHeadings -> {None, {"Options", "AbsoluteTiming", "Result"}}]
```

[image]