# Is there anyway to reduce the time for the numerical integration of this formula?

Tags: numerical-integration, performance-tuning, special-functions

I'm trying to do the following series of computations.

```
data = Import["http://www.vibrationdata.com/elcentro_EW.dat"];
Acc = Interpolation[data];
c = 1500; rho = 1; H = 80;
p[y_, t_] := (4*rho*c)/π*
   Sum[(-1)^(n - 1)/(2 n - 1.) Cos[(2 n - 1.) π/(2 H) y]*
     NIntegrate[
      BesselJ[0, (2 n - 1) π/(2 H)*c*(t - τ)] * Acc[τ], 
       {τ, 0, t}], {n, 1, 20}];

(* the following takes a long time and I would like to make it fast *)
(* Table[{p[10, t]}, {t, 0, 8, .1}]; *)
```

The list of data is shown below. The data can be found here:http://www.vibrationdata.com/elcentro_EW.dat
[image]

And the constants values are:
c=1500, rho=1, H=80.

Is there anyway to accelerate this computation? I want to evaluate p at y=10.

Thank you.

Comment: We cannot experiment with the code since you have not provided representative `data` with which to work nor the value of the constants `{\[Rho], c, H}`.

Comment: Sorry for that, I edited the question.

Comment: @Mr.Pi That's ok, but people here generally like users to post code in a form that they can copy-paste it directly into *Mathematica*. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.

Comment: Try using `Method -> "InterpolationPointsSubdivision"`.

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/115860/how-to-speed-up-integration-of-interpolation-function

Answer (score 4):

To be really fast, you bypass `NIntegrate`.  But you can only do that if you know ahead of time what sort of sampling you need, since you lose two great advantages of `NIntegrate`, adaptive sampling and error estimation. In this case, the integral consists cubic polynomials times a Bessel function over many, small intervals of the same width. (The cubic polynomials come from the interpolating function `Acc`).  Well, this is not a hopeless situation for Gauss-Legendre integration.  The oscillations of the Bessel function in a given interval increase linearly with `n` in the OP's formula.  One expects to have to add a couple of Gauss points for each oscillation. Next one needs a starting number of points for `n = 1`.  I used `5` at first but then I started testing (not shown*) the accuracy and found that `3` is sufficient for 7-8 digits precision.

```
Clear[p, gaussrule, grdata];
mem : grdata[n_] := mem = NIntegrate`GaussRuleData[n, MachinePrecision];
gaussrule[f_, gp_, intervals_?(MatrixQ[#, NumericQ] &)] := 
  Module[{abscissae, weights},
   {abscissae, weights} = Most@grdata[gp];
   f@Map[
      #[[1]] + abscissae (#[[2]] - #[[1]]) &,
      intervals
      ].weights.Subtract[intervals[[All, 2]], intervals[[All, 1]]]
   ];

c = 1500; rho = 1; H = 80;
p[y_, t_] := 
  With[{intervals = Partition[Append[TakeWhile[data[[All, 1]], # < t &], N@t], 2, 1]},
   (4*rho*c)/π*
    Sum[
     (-1)^(n - 1)/(2 n - 1) Cos[(2 n - 1) π/(2 H) y]*
      gaussrule[
       Function[τ, BesselJ[0, (2 n - 1) π/(2 H)*c*(t - τ)] * Acc[τ]],
       Ceiling[3 + n/2],  (* Gauss points heuristic *)
       intervals],
     {n, 1, 20}]
   ];
```

I said "really fast" at the beginning, but that's only in comparison with the OP's code:

```
Table[{p[10, t]}, {t, 0, 8, .1}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {29.541, Null}  *)
```

For comparison, for `p[10, 8]`, this method takes `0.67` s., the OP's method `31.4` s., and `Method -> "InterpolationPointsSubdivision"` `16.8` s.

*Note: Testing can be done by observing the convergence of the computed values as the number of points is increased, for instance.  I did not do a thorough testing.  The accuracy is inferred from the theory of convergence of Gauss-Legendre integration and a few spot checks.  The 7-8 digits was determined by a couple of high-precision tests using the same approach as `gaussrule` but with greater number of points and 32-digit precision numbers.  These checks took less than ten seconds and were still much faster than `NIntegrate`.

Another note: `BesselJ` unpacks packed arrays. Consequently, I didn't try to keep things packed: you often lose some time when they get packed, because they are then unpacked.