# N[Integrate] failing to return an accurate result from an interpolated integrand

Tags: numerical-integration, interpolation

I need to N[Integrate] a function `Cos[alpha*x]*f(x)` between x=0 and 30 at increasing alpha-values. Here f(x) is an interpolated function derived from a set of 120 equally-spaced points belonging to the Gaussian `0.095*Exp[-x^2/35.28]` between x=0 and 30. An example for alpha=2 is given below:

```
curve = Import["G1_theor_ZrH2.txt", {"Data", All, {1, 2}}]
intercurve = Interpolation[curve]
Plot[intercurve[x], {x, 0, 30}]
```

[image]

The interpolated function gets perfectly superimposed to the Gaussian in the above-mentioned range (and, in general, between x=-70 and 70).

Now, the problematic integrand is `Cos[2*x]*intercurve[x]`, which is an oscillating Gaussian profile:

```
Plot[intercurve[x]*Cos[2*x], {x, 0, 30}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image]

Indeed, the exact integration of the exact curve over a non-finite range returns:

```
Integrate[0.095*Exp[-x^2/35.28]*Cos[2*x], {x, 0, Infinity}]
2.383*10^-16
```

If I try to perform an N[Integration] of the same exact curve over [0,50], I can find an accurate estimation if compared to the exact value:

```
N[Integrate[0.095*Exp[-x^2/35.28]*Cos[2*x], {x, 0, 50}], 20]
2.383*10^-16 + 5.90865*10^-47 I
```

If the integration range gets shrunk to [0,30] the evaluation turns out quite worse:

```
N[Integrate[0.095*Exp[-x^2/35.28]*Cos[2*x], {x, 0, 30}], 20]
1.18736*10^-13 + 0. I
```

When the same couple integrations is applied to the interpolated integrand, Mathematica returns:

```
N[Integrate[intercurve[x]*Cos[2*x], {x, 0, 50}], 20]
NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small. >>
NIntegrate::eincr: The global error of the strategy GlobalAdaptive has increased more than 400 times. The global error is expected to decrease monotonically after a number of integrand evaluations. Suspect one of the following: the working precision is insufficient for the specified precision goal; the integrand is highly oscillatory or it is not a (piecewise) smooth function; or the true value of the integral is 0. Increasing the value of the GlobalAdaptive option MaxErrorIncreases might lead to a convergent numerical integration. NIntegrate obtained -0.0000461585926263450153769201220002 and 1.79688309588571048164765344384`30.*^-18 for the integral and error estimates. >>
-0.0000461585926263450153769201220002
```

and

```
N[Integrate[intercurve[x]*Cos[2*x], {x, 0, 30}], 20]
NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small.
NIntegrate::eincr: The global error of the strategy GlobalAdaptive has increased more than 400 times. The global error is expected to decrease monotonically after a number of integrand evaluations. Suspect one of the following: the working precision is insufficient for the specified precision goal; the integrand is highly oscillatory or it is not a (piecewise) smooth function; or the true value of the integral is 0. Increasing the value of the GlobalAdaptive option MaxErrorIncreases might lead to a convergent numerical integration. NIntegrate obtained -0.0000461616042074379102542229207380 and 1.7968766559320907492916850148`30.*^-18 for the integral and error estimates. >>
-0.0000461616042074379102542229207380
```

Trying to enlarge MaxErrorIncrease as suggested has no healing effect:

```
NIntegrate[intercurve[x]*Cos[2*x], {x, 0, 30}, WorkingPrecision -> 20,
AccuracyGoal -> Infinity, 
Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "MaxErrorIncreases" -> 10000}]
-0.000046161604207438302512
```

I also tried to both partition the integral of the interpolated function into a sum of integrations between pairs of zeroes and artificially 'inflate' the integrand by a suitable constant factor to be removed later, but niet.

As expected, things go fine at lower values of alpha (alpha<0.7) for both the exact and the interpolated integrand, due to the decrease in number of oscillations and the dramatic increase in global subtended area, which makes the contribution from the removed Gaussian tails non-significant.
However, my question is: why the same N[Integration] of `Cos[2*x]*intercurve[x]` and `Cos[2*x]*0.095*Exp[-x^2/35.28]` returns values that different, despite the two functions being visually identical over the same integration range?

Comment: Would be good to 1) include a code block that we can copy-paste and run to reproduce your issue which 2) you should specify in your question. So what is the actual problem? Warnings, inexact results, nothing happens? ... My guess would be that the results are off from the exact value, which you might be able to solve with a much higher `WorkingPrecision`

Comment: Hi Lukas - I've just edited my post according to your suggestions - I'm new to this community, sorry.
Enhancing `WorkingPrecision` make results show a larger number of digits, but does not improve their accuracy.

Comment: Right now i cannot run code, but you might want to replace your decimal numbers by exact values, e.g. 35.28 -> 3528/1000. Also, see what happens if you use the option `WorkingPrecision->100` for `NIntegrate`

Comment: Btw, we need the data in order to get your `curvature`

Comment: Ooops!
Looks like I have no enough reputation to include other links into the post - you can find my data here: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/gjcywi077c917ky?oref=e&r=AAJgriQijessuKB58sR20ndea80yh_4Rx5GaOi9CnBOJTVcJeicJaxWHuhWQjEeBH_qZCyFT5w8WZ4FEvXPKsj7zVC_OnR7urGEOrEwr00fJvGYwsGHWrq4qlyU0ziexE12MHZAh6ZaiZ2MKZFXCmi-SgewKk7ERufEx4De_4D2lWIY1YCoBRKaSqTCuL2Trfnd5HP1dleGvp0b3KpQPdQDe&sm=1)
No improvements from replacing decimal numbers by exact values. Setting `WorkingPrecision`=100 makes Mathematica fail to converge near {x} = {1.25.....} and return the usual result (-0.00004616...).

Comment: one thing to note, your `Integrate` expressions are returning machine precision values (indeed you have machine precision values in the input expression). Wrapping them in `N[..,20]` isn't doing anything.

Comment: I suspect in the interpolation case your approximate function simply is just enough different that it gives an incorrect result. Even though it looks the same you are subtracting large neg and pos quantites to get a near zero result so small errors will be amplified. I would seek out a quadrature scheme that only uses the supplied data points (No interpolation).  (Perhaps more of a math.stackexchange.com question).

Comment: That's a good suggestion, George - especially in the view of f(x) being an experimental NCP profile with no analytical control model behind it (the spherical average of a multivariate 3D Gaussian). Gonna try. Thanks to all of you for your helpful comments.

Comment: Alexandra, can you please try adding the option `Method -> "InterpolationPointsSubdivision"` to your `NIntegrate[]` involving the interpolated function that you have?

Comment: Just done - no improvements. Looks like adjusting the `MaxSubregions` option of `InterpolationPointsSubdivision` to  the number of intervals created by the interpolation points could produce more accurate results, but I don't know where to recover this number.

Comment: try MaxSubregions -> Length@ intercurve["Grid"] or thereabouts

Comment: See http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18863/how-to-integrate-functions-of-linearly-interpolated-data/39403#39403 (search for the option to see an example).

Comment: Ok, looks like the problem is not solvable from an 'experimental' point of view. Any chance to approximate the integral over the non-finite range by its finite counterpart (over [0,30]) at large alphas gets crushed due to the transfer of a significant part of the integral into the removed asymptotic tail when the number of oscillations is high. I'd need to enlarge the finite data range to overcome this obstacle, but I can't, since it's a limit set by the spectrometer's sensitivity. Ok, that makes sense to me - Mathematica works well - and you guys are so helpful!