# Storage of interpolated data

Tags: numerical-integration, interpolation

I successfully imported some optical data to Mathematica, which I need to interpolate to use it as a proper function. The command `data=Interpolation[]` was quite helpful, but know I'm in doubt whether it is the best way to define a function `f[x_]:=data[x]` when the function will later be called upon in a numerical integration with `NIntegrate[]`.

What is the best way to store the interpolated data in terms of computational time when using it later in `NIntegrate[]`? Any advice is highly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: There's no reason you can't `NIntegrate[]` an `InterpolationFunction`

Comment: Yes, but compared to a non-interpolated function it takes much more computational time. That's the reason why I was wondering whether there is a more efficient way to store the interpolated values.

Comment: I don't think that's true, at least not when you always use `NIntegrate[]`

Comment: Ok, so if there is no other way that is more efficient I have to stick to this method and see how I can otherwise improve my code.

Comment: Actually let me amend that, it seems to depend on the exact data used. I guess you can try to `FindFit[]` instead?

Comment: …are the data noisy, or are they exact? (Interpolate in the first case, and fit in the second case.)

Comment: Unfortunately, they are pretty noisy with various peaks. Don't think you could find a proper fit. Interpolation should be right here.

Comment: Note that you can `Integrate` an `InterpolatingFunction`, since it is a piecewise-polynomial function and therefore easy to piecewise-integrate. (I learned that here somewhere.)

Comment: @march +1! Interesting, that makes it faster than Integrating even regular functions.

Comment: @Feyre. The issue I've run into, of course, is that you can *only* do `Integrate[func[x], {x, ...}]`, where `func` is the `InterpolatingFunction`. As soon as you do e.g. `Integrate[x^2 func[x], {x, ...}]`, it fails to integrate, even though one would hope that *Mathematica* would recognize that `x^2*func[x]` is still piecewise-polynomial.

Comment: "pretty noisy with various peaks" - then interpolation is apparently not what you want, unless you want a function that faithfully reproduces those "noisy peaks".

Comment: Potentially related: "[How to integrate functions of linearly interpolated data?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18863/280)"

Comment: Maybe "pretty noisy" was the wrong expression. I mean it's detailed data of a typical dieletric function of a material with certain peaks, but not completely messed up. I looked at the interpolated curves and they look pretty nice, but the integration time afterwards take a lot of time, unfortunately.