# Integrating of Interpolation function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, performance-tuning, interpolation

I am using `Interpolation` to construct an `InterpolatingFunction` from several points. I do not need a higher order `InterpolationOrder` than 1.

I wonder, in this case, is the contructed `InterpolatingFunction` simply a piecewise linear function? My goal is to Integrate that function, but due to performance reasons, I need to get the primitive function (evaluate the non-definite integral first). But I am wondering, whether this can be done and whether the result would be piecewise quadratic function so that the operation $F(x_i)$, where $F(x)=\int f(x)\,{\rm d} x$ and $f(x)$ is the `InterpolatingFunction` is as fast as plugging into a piecewise defined $\tilde{F}(x) = a_ix^2+b_ix +c_i$.

So in Mathematica, the code should look like:

```
f=Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
F[x_]:=Integral[f[x],x];
result = Exp[F[#]]&/@biglistofx;
```

Are there any other performance issues that I should be aware when using `Interpolation` and its integration?

If the `Interpolation` does not produce a piecewise linear function, what would be my best approach to make the above calculation as fast as possible (note that `Length@biglistofx` $\sim 10^7$)?

Comment: Strongly related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18863/280

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Integrate` will compute the antiderivative of an `InterpolatingFunction`:

```
data = Table[Sin[x], {x, 1., 10.}];
f = Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
F[x_] = Integrate[f[x], x] (* with =, not := *)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Plot[{f[x], F[x]}, {x, 1, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Timing (`InterpolatingFunction` and `Exp` automatically threads over lists, so there's no need for `Map`; it's faster this way, too):

```
result = Exp[F[#]] &@ RandomReal[{1, 10}, 10^7]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {18.2411, Null}  *)

Length@result
(*  10000000  *)
```

Comment: You can also use `Derivative[-1][f]` to generate the pure function (i.e. `InterpolatingFunction` without the argument `x`) antiderivative.

Comment: But are the `InterpolatingFunction` and its integral simple functions like piece wise defined linear/quadratic functions or are they more complex Mathematica internal expressions (and thus requiring more computation time)? Or in other words, can they be displayed as a piecewise definition?

Comment: @leosenko The interpolating function is computed via an algorithm, no doubt optimized for its task.  It's about 100 times slower than a simple math function like `Exp` and about 6 times faster than the correspond `Piecewise` function. I'd be surprised (and interested) if the interpolating function can be beat.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from Michael's and Carl's suggestions, you can also use `NDSolve[]` to generate the interpolant corresponding to the integral of the original `InterpolatingFunction[]`:

```
data = Table[Sin[x], {x, 1., 10.}];
f = Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
F = NDSolveValue[{ff'[x] == f[x], ff[1] == 0}, ff, {x, 1, 10}];

Plot[{f[x], F[x]}, {x, 1, 10}]
```

[image: plot of interpolant and its integral]