# integrate one vector of data points with respect to another from a file

Tags: numerical-integration, import

I have a data file with two columns. Column 1 is x-values and column 2 is f(x) values. I would like to integrate f(x) with respect to x. To load the data, I do this:

```
mydata = ReadList["/dataset0.txt", Number, RecordLists -> True];
```

It reads the data file correctly. Now how do I insert the corresponding columns in a Integrate function?

Comment: related https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18863/2079

Comment: 1) Welcome on MMA.SE, 2) that would be easier to help you with some dummy data (possiby using `RandomReals`, or pastebin.com), 3) you don't want to integrate, you want to approximate the integral, using data and an approximation scheme (which one? trapezoidal, etc.).

Comment: Thank you for helpful comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link provided by @george2079 in the comments will be very useful if you run into more technical problems. I'm going to assume that it's all plain sailing, and just go through how integrating from data can work using `Interpolation`.

Here's some fake data with the same structure as yours:

```
mydata = {#, Sin[#^2]} &@RandomReal[π, 100];
```

which gives you a list of x-values and a list of function values (which I'm pretending is `Sin[x^2]`). Without an explicit expression for your function, you'll have to approximate the integral somehow. One straightforward way of doing this is with an `InterpolatingFunction`.

```
infun = Interpolation[Transpose[mydata]];
Show[ListPlot[Transpose[mydata]], 
  Plot[infun[x], Evaluate@Flatten@{x, infun["Domain"]}]]
```

[image]

Then you can `Integrate` `infun`, using the domain stored in the `InterpolatingFunction`

```
Integrate[infun[x], Evaluate@Flatten@{x, infun["Domain"]}]
(* 0.788024 *)
```

Compare with the actual function

```
Integrate[Sin[x^2], Evaluate@Flatten@{x, infun["Domain"]}]
(* 0.788037 *)
```

The discrepancy is due to the fact that `infun` is an approximation. The more data points you have, the more accurate it will be. Obviously.

**Update:** As @anderstood points out, you can also implement a straighforward rectangular rule on the sorted data:

```
mydata = {#, Sin[#^2]} &@Sort@RandomReal[\[Pi], 100];
xlist = Differences[mydata[[1]]];

Total[xlist mydata[[2, ;; -2]]] (* forward *)
Total[xlist mydata[[2, 2 ;; ]]] (* backward *)

(* 0.76924
   0.808697 *)
```

which may not be quite as accurate, but improves greatly for large data sets and is a couple of orders of magnitude faster.

Comment: Another approach, using a rectangular rule: `mydata = {#, Sin[#^2]} &@Sort@RandomReal[\[Pi], 100]; xlist = Differences[mydata[[1]]]; Total[xlist*mydata[[2, ;; -2]]]` (change to `mydata[[2, 2 ;; ]]` to switch between forward and backward rule).

Comment: @anderstood Absolutely. Depending on the size of the data, the nastiness of the function, and how much speed is a factor, that might be a better method.

Comment: Thank you. This is very helpful