# What's the best method to use when NIntegrating a sinx + cosx type function?

Tags: numerical-integration, warning-messages, numerical-value, precision-and-accuracy

I'm having some problems when trying to `NIntegrate` a sinx + cosx type function. I have already tryed several combinations of `AccuracyGoal`, `PrecisionGoal`, `WorkingPrecision`, `MaxRecursion` and `MinRecursion` but it doesn't seem to help. So maybe changing the integration method would be better, but I don't know which one I should use in this case.

Any suggestions?

The function I'm trying to `NIntegrate` is defined as:

```
Integrand3[ω_, t_] := Cos[ω t - m ϕv[t]] Re[SSCGFTInt3[ω]] + Sin[ω t - m ϕv[t]] Im[SSCGFTInt3[ω]]
```

Where `t`, `m` and `ϕv[t]` are previously defined parameters. The integration is performed as a function of `ω`, and `SSCGFTInt3[ω]` is an interpolated function.

I'm attaching a link with an example and also `SSCGFTInt3` data: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1cysFWpPeTz-L-KTA9kCclLYAIesrR9-f?usp=sharing

As you can see, the last plot has an oscillatory behavior from t=100 to t=400, and it **should not** be happening.

Comment: Could you, please, post the exact function that you are considering?

Comment: @bmf just added!! :)

Comment: Many thanks for that. From a quick look, I am inclined to say that the issues are due to the `SSCGFTInt3` function rather than `Cos` and `Sin`. And also, in order for us to do the numerical integration, we need that function and the values for `t` and `φv[t]`

Comment: @bmf hope it'll help.

Comment: For the type of integrand in the title with a smooth function `f[]`, `NIntegrate[f[Cos[t] + Sin[t]], {t, 0, T}, Method -> "Trapezoidal"]`, but for the integrand in the question, perhaps `NIntegrate[Re[SSCGFTInt3[\[Omega]]  E^(-I*(t*\[Omega] - m*\[Phi]v[t]))], {t, 0, T}, Method -> {"InterpolationPointsSubdivision", "MaxSubregions" -> 1 + Length[First@SSCGFTInt3["Coordinates"]]}]` (see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/39403/4999) or [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/39405/4999))

Comment: @MichaelE2 unfortunately it didn't help... Is there any other method I can use?